# String manipulation in React/JS

Tags: reactjs

I am really new to js. Unable to do this :

```
"polygonCoordinates": [
            "(3.0, 0.0)",
            "(3.0, 5.0)",
            "(8.0, 12.0)",
            "(3.0, 0.0)"
        ],
```

Needs to be converted to :

```
polyCoords : [
        { lat: 3.0, lng: 0.0 },
        { lat: 3.0, lng: 5.0 },
        { lat: 8.0, lng: 12.0 },
        { lat: 3.0, lng: 0.0  }
      ]
```

Comment: Is this inside an object? How do you have " around `polytgonCoordinates`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.map` with 1 `regex`: `/\((.+)\,(.+)\)/` can solve your problem.

```js
const input = {
  "polygonCoordinates": [
    "(3.0, 0.0)",
    "(3.0, 5.0)",
    "(8.0, 12.0)",
    "(3.0, 0.0)"
  ]
};

const str = `(3.0, 0.0)`;
let m;

const regex = /\((.+)\,(.+)\)/;

let finalResult = {};
finalResult.polyCoords = input.polygonCoordinates.map(item => {
   let result = {};
   if ((m = regex.exec(item)) !== null) {
      result.lat = parseFloat(m[1].trim());
      result.long = parseFloat(m[2].trim());
   }
   return result;
});

console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {"polygonCoordinates": [
            "(3.0, 0.0)",
            "(3.0, 5.0)",
            "(8.0, 12.0)",
            "(3.0, 0.0)"
        ]}
        
const mapped = {polyCoords: data["polygonCoordinates"].map(d => {
   const splitted = d.split(/[(,)]/)
   return {lat: parseFloat(splitted[1]), lng: parseFloat(splitted[2])}
})}

console.log(mapped)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [
"(3.0, 0.0)",
"(3.0, 5.0)",
"(8.0, 12.0)",
"(3.0, 0.0)"
];
var polycords = [];
arr.forEach(item=>{
    const lat = item.split(',')[0].replace('(','');
    const lng = item.split(',')[1].replace(')','');
    polycords.push({lat,lng}); 
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a regular expression to extract the values, a [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operation, and [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert the strings to numbers:

```js
const data = {
  "polygonCoordinates": [
    "(3.0, 0.0)",
    "(3.0, 5.0)",
    "(8.0, 12.0)",
    "(3.0, 0.0)"
  ]
};

const result = {
  polycoords: data['polygonCoordinates'].map(s => {
    const [_, x, y] = s.match(/\((.+?), (.+?)\)/);
    return { lat: parseFloat(x), lng: parseFloat(y) };
  })
};

console.log(result);
```